# Health Monitoring and WCF

Tags: .net, wcf, health-monitoring

I'd like to use Health Monitoring to log unhandled exceptions that I trap in my own Error Handler:

```
public class MyErrorHandler : IErrorHandler, IServiceBehavior
{
    #region IServiceBehavior Members
    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase, System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection endpoints, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
        IErrorHandler errorHandler = new VirusInfoErrorHandler();

        foreach (ChannelDispatcherBase channelDispatcherBase in serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers)
        {
            ChannelDispatcher channelDispatcher = channelDispatcherBase as ChannelDispatcher;

            if (channelDispatcher != null)
            {
                channelDispatcher.ErrorHandlers.Add(errorHandler);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
    }

    #endregion

    #region IErrorHandler Members

    public bool HandleError(Exception ex)
    {
        MyErrorEvent l_errEvt = new MyErrorEvent("Oh Noes!", this, WebEventCodes.WebExtendedBase + 2, ex);

        // Always throws a "Value does not fall within the expected range" ArgumentException.
        l_errEvt.Raise();                

        return true;
    }

    public void ProvideFault(Exception error, MessageVersion version, ref Message fault)
    {
    }

    #endregion    
}
```

I'm using a very simple custom WebRequestErrorEvent at the moment:

```
public MyErrorEvent(string message, object eventSource, int eventCode, Exception exception)
    : base(message, eventSource, WebEventCodes.WebExtendedBase + eventCode, exception)
{

}

public override void FormatCustomEventDetails(WebEventFormatter formatter)
{
    if (formatter == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("formatter", "Please supply a valid formatter object.");
    }

    try
    {
        base.FormatCustomEventDetails(formatter);

        formatter.AppendLine("this was a bad error");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

The exception's stack trace is:

```
at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
at System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.GetServerVariableInternal(String name)
at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_UrlInternal()
at System.Web.Management.WebRequestInformation..ctor()
at System.Web.Management.WebRequestErrorEvent.PreProcessEventInit()
at System.Web.Management.WebBaseEvent.RaiseInternal(WebBaseEvent eventRaised, ArrayList firingRuleInfos, Int32 index0, Int32 index1)
at System.Web.Management.WebBaseEvent.Raise(WebBaseEvent eventRaised)
at System.Web.Management.WebBaseEvent.Raise()
at ACME.MyErrorHandler.HandleError(Exception ex) in G:\Code\MySvc\Lib\ACME.ErrorHandler\MyErrorHandler.cs:line 78
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ErrorBehavior.HandleErrorCommon(Exception error, ErrorHandlerFaultInfo& faultInfo)
```

Can a WebRequestErrorEvent not be used with WCF?  I can raise WebRequestEvents with no problems, but not WebRequestErrorEvents.

Comment: Are you open to something like Windows Server AppFabric plugged into IIS?  It's an amazing monitoring service for WCF and WF services.  If you're open to that I'll post an answer with more information.

Comment: I definitely am interested in AppFabric.  I'm hosting it in IIS7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2 at the moment, but I would need to know more about hosting it in AppFabric (I do have it installed but that's as far as I got :)).

Answer (score 0):

OK, so because it may be somewhat redundant for me to put up instructions for getting AppFabric working in your situation I'm going to post some helpful links instead.

The first thing you'll need to do is configure the Monitoring database in the AppServer Fabric configuration application -- under Windows Programs.

Setup: In this link by @RonJacobs -- love that guy, thanks Ron for all you do -- he gives some great detail regarding setting everything up in IIS.  The most interesting piece for you will be Enable End-to-End Tracking - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjacobs/archive/2010/06/09/tracking-wcf-data-services-with-windows-server-appfabric.aspx.

Troubleshooting: In this link there is some great troubleshooting information once you get it running initially - http://www.lhotka.net/weblog/WindowsServerAppFabricAndWCFMonitoring.aspx.

Let me know if you run into any problems and I'll help as much as I can!

Comment: Thanks for the info!  One thing I haven't been able to find is the process of setting up the reporting database.  Ideally, I'd like to host the database on a different machine than the one hosting my web service. For example, if I already have AppFabric installed on my web server, can I simply supply a connection string in my web.config to a reporting database server (and does the database server require the full AppFabric install as well)?

Comment: @Bullines In short, the database can be on any available SQL server and AppFabric only needs to be installed on the IIS Server. Are you having trouble finding the AppFabric configuration wizard? Here is a link to walk through that [link]http://www.nagarro.com/blog/windows-server-appfabric/.

Comment: From the looks of it, I have to reinstall AppFabric to get to the Configuration Wizard again?

Comment: That's possible -- and as an FYI, I've always installed it by downloading it from the Web Platform Installer.